# Не устанавливаются Cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, angular, asp.net-identity-2

Во время авторизации аккаунта с сервера (.net 6 asp.net core) приходит Set-Cookie. На фронтенде (angular 17.0.9) это отображается, Однако cookie не устанавливаются. Backend запускается на порту 5001. Angular на 4200. В чем может быть проблемма?
[image: установка cookie]

[image: демонстрация отстутсвия куков]
Роут контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> Login([FromBody] UserLoginDTO user)
{
    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.Login, user.Password, true, false);
    var returnedData = new LoginUserDataDTO();
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        returnedData.Login = user.Login;
        returnedData.Error = false;
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnedData);
    }
    else
    {
        returnedData.Error = true;
        returnedData.ErrorMessage = "Wrong login or password";
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnedData);
    }
}
```

Program:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("DevCorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials();
}));

// DB Services
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AMContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AMIdentityContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

builder.Services.AddIdentity<DBUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
    config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    config.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
    config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    config.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AMIdentityContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseCors("DevCorsPolicy"); // TODO edit to before deploy
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.MapControllers();

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("TaskParser", (method) => method.TaskParser(), "*/1 * * * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("PostParser", (method) => method.PostParser(), "*/1 * * * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("MonitorStatus", (method) => method.MonitorStatus(), "*/1 * * * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("CommentParser", (method) => method.CommentParser(), "*/1 * * * * *");
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangFireTaskManager>("LikesParser", (method) => method.LikesParser(), "*/1 * * * * *");

// Init Roles
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        var rolesManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        await RoleInitializer.InitializeAsync(rolesManager);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
    }
}

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Решением тало запуск фронтенда вместе с backend на 1-ом порту.